Where did Alston express the last sentence's objection against doxastic voluntarianism?
The deontological conception of epistemic justification, e.g. in the version according to which a person is justified in holding p just in the case she is in some sense, normatively permitted to believe that p, has come under attack. According to William Alston, the major defect of epistemic deontologism is that it presupposes doxastic voluntarism, i.e. the view that we have direct voluntary control over whether to believe something or not. But Alston thinks that we have no such direct voluntary control, or rather that we only quite rarely have such control. And given this alleged failure of the prevalence of voluntary control, Alston maintained that "it is futile to discuss whether I am permitted to believe that p at t or whether I would be irresponsible in choosing to believe that p at t."

@KristianBerry You may expand it into a full answer by finding its location in the original paper here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/43153972

@KristianBerry I am sorry about that. FYI, it is on page 196.
